# Cannot access Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemCollection.Size

Tags: uwp, c++17, winrt-xaml, c++-winrt

Im fairly new to C++ so sorry if this is obvious, but I cannot access the property 'Size' on the type Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemCollection.

Here is my code:

```
Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::ItemCollection& items = Items(); // Items in a property of Windows::UI::Xaml::Controls::GridView which my class derives from
auto count = items.Size(); // -> build error
```

The error is **'winrt::impl::consume_Windows_Foundation_Collections_IVector::Size': a function that returns 'auto' cannot be used before it is defined**

I know that ItemCollection has a Size property, so why is the compiler complaining that it isnt defined.

Any help would be really appreciated

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You forgot to include a header file that provides the definition of the template, probably `<winrt/Windows.Foundation.Collections.h`. This particular compiler error used to be a linker error, that was a lot harder to interpret.

Raymond Chen blogged about the changes that went into C++/WinRT to 'promote' this linker error into a compiler error: [Why does my C++/WinRT project get errors of the form “consume_Something: function that returns ‘auto’ cannot be used before it is defined”?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190530-00/?p=102529)

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh (slaps forehead with hand). Of course - thank you so much. Ive been trying to work that one out for a while, thought I had gotten confused over pointers (which is my usual trick). Thanks again